# Explanation of the different tags in django's admin default change_form.html template

Tags: django

Where can i find explanation of the different tags in django's admin default change_form.html template?

Answer (score 0):

use the source

```
{% load i18n admin_modify adminmedia %}
```

so we look in

`$django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py`

where e.g. `submit_row` is defined.

are there any tags in particular you are wondering about?